# pandas: finding the root of a function

Tags: pandas

I have some data frame in pandas, where the columns can be viewed as smooth functions of the index:

```
       f     g
 x  ------------
0.1 f(0.1) g(0.1)
0.2 f(0.2) g(0.2)

...
```

And I want to know the `x` value for some `f(x) = y` -- where `y` is a given, and I don't necessarily have a point at the `x` that I am looking for.

Essentially I want to find the intersection of a line and a data series in pandas.  Is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your DataFrame looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def unknown_func(x):
    return -x ** 3 + 1

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'f': unknown_func(x)}, index=x)
```

then, using scipy, you could [create an interpolation function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html):

```
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate
func = interpolate.interp1d(x, df['f'], kind='linear')
```

and then [use a root finder](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) to solve `f(x)-y=0` for x:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
root = optimize.brentq(lambda x: func(x)-y, x.min(), x.max())
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

def unknown_func(x):
    return -x ** 3 + 1

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'f': unknown_func(x)}, index=x)

y = 50
func = interpolate.interp1d(x, df['f'], kind='linear')
root = optimize.brentq(lambda x: func(x)-y, x.min(), x.max())
print(root)
# -3.6566397064

print(func(root))
# 50.0

idx = np.searchsorted(df.index.values, root)
print(df.iloc[idx-1:idx+1])
#                    f
# -3.737374  53.203496
# -3.535354  45.187410
```

---

Notice that you need some model for your data. Above, the linear interpolator,
[`interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) is implicitly imposing a model for the unknown function that
generated the data.

If you already have a model function (such as `unknown_func`), then you could use that instead of the `func` returned by `interp1d`.  If
you have a parametrized model function, then instead of `interp1d` you could use
[`optimize.curve_fit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to find the best fitting parameters.  And if you do choose
to interpolate, there are many other choices (e.g. quadratic or cubic
interpolation) for interpolation which you might use too. What to choose depends on what you think best models your data.